# Button onPressed callback is a Navigation command, doesnt navigate when pressed on

Tags: flutter, callback, navigation, flutter-onpressed

I'm making my own custom Floating Action Button
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../routes.dart';
import 'circularbutton.dart';

class WidgetFABMarket extends StatefulWidget {
  const WidgetFABMarket({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WidgetFABMarketState createState() => _WidgetFABMarketState();
}

class _WidgetFABMarketState extends State with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;
  late Animation degOneTranslationAnimation,
      degTwoTranslationAnimation,
      degThreeTranslationAnimation;
  late Animation rotationAnimation;

  double getRadiansFromDegree(double degree) {
    double unitRadian = 57.295779513;
    return degree / unitRadian;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250));
    degOneTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem(tween: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.2), weight: 75.0),
      TweenSequenceItem(tween: Tween(begin: 1.2, end: 1.0), weight: 25.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degTwoTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem(tween: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.4), weight: 55.0),
      TweenSequenceItem(tween: Tween(begin: 1.4, end: 1.0), weight: 45.0)
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degThreeTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence([
      TweenSequenceItem(tween: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.75), weight: 35.0),
      TweenSequenceItem(tween: Tween(begin: 1.75, end: 1.0), weight: 65.0)
    ]).animate(animationController);
    rotationAnimation = Tween(begin: 180.0, end: 0.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut));
    super.initState();
    animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          right: 10,
          bottom: 10,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),
                    degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 75),
                child: Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                      getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                    ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.storefront,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onClick: () {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushNamed(RouteGenerator.marketPage);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),
                    degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 150),
                child: Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                      getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                    ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.phone_android,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onClick: () {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushNamed(RouteGenerator.myShopPage);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),
                    degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 225),
                child: Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                      getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                    ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.bookmarks_outlined,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onClick: () {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushNamed(RouteGenerator.bookmarkPage);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),
                    degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 300),
                child: Transform(
                  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                      getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                    ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: CircularButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.manage_search,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onClick: () {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushNamed(RouteGenerator.searchPage);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                    getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value)),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: CircularButton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.menu,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onClick: () {
                    if (animationController.isCompleted) {
                      animationController.reverse();
                    } else {
                      animationController.forward();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CircularButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color color;
  final Icon icon;
  final VoidCallback onClick;

  CircularButton(
      {Key? key,
        required this.color,
        required this.width,
        required this.height,
        required this.icon,
        required this.onClick})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Center(
            child: Ink(
              decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                shape: CircleBorder(),
              ),
              width: width,
              height: height,
              child:
              IconButton(icon: icon, enableFeedback: true, onPressed: onClick),
            )));
  }
}
```

The main Floating Action Button(FAB) is clickable and does trigger the expansion of 4 smaller FABs. When I click on any of the small FABs, nothing happens, the Navigation call is not triggered...
The onCLick call for the main FAB, an if statement for the animationController, does trigger normally.
The onCLick call for the smaller FABs, Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RouteGenerator.myShopPage), doesn't trigger.

For the record, Navigation is set up and works in other part of the app by using the exact same call, .pushNamed(RouteGenerator.myShopPage). Also the Pages, destinations, for my small FABs are setup as well.

I'm a bit lost. I think the problem comes from the callback type in the CustomButton widget but can't figure it out.

Is it a callback typing problem or something entirely else?

EDIT: I'm adding the route page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'routes/common/helppage.dart';
import 'routes/common/homepage.dart';
import 'routes/common/loginpage.dart';
import 'routes/common/settingspage.dart';
import 'routes/market/bookmark.dart';
import 'routes/market/bookmarkmap.dart';
import 'routes/market/market.dart';
import 'routes/market/resultsdetails.dart';
import 'routes/market/resultsdetailsmap.dart';
import 'routes/market/resultspage.dart';
import 'routes/market/searchpage.dart';
import 'routes/myshop/myshoppage.dart';
import 'routes/myshop/postsalepage.dart';
import 'routes/myshop/saledetailspage.dart';
import 'routes/myshop/updatesalepage.dart';

class RouteGenerator {
  const RouteGenerator._();

  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case loginPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<LoginPage>(
          builder: (_) => const LoginPage(title:"Login"),
        );
      case homePage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<HomePage>(
          builder: (_) => const HomePage(title:"Home"),
        );
      case helpPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<HelpPage>(
          builder: (_) => const HelpPage(title:"Help"),
        );
      case settingsPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<SettingsPage>(
          builder: (_) => const SettingsPage(title:"Settings"),
        );

      case marketPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<MarketPage>(
          builder: (_) => const MarketPage(title:"Market"),
        );
      case searchPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<SearchPage>(
          builder: (_) => const SearchPage(title:"Search"),
        );
      case resultsPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<ResultsPage>(
          builder: (_) => const ResultsPage(title:"Search results"),
        );
      case resultsDetailsPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<ResultsDetailsPage>(
          builder: (_) => const ResultsDetailsPage(title:"Details"),
        );
      case resultsDetailsMapPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<ResultsDetailsMapPage>(
          builder: (_) => const ResultsDetailsMapPage(title:"Location"),
        );
      case bookmarkPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<BookmarkPage>(
          builder: (_) => const BookmarkPage(title:"Bookmark details"),
        );
      case bookmarkMapPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<BookmarkMapPage>(
          builder: (_) => const BookmarkMapPage(title:"Location"),
        );

      case myShopPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<MyShopPage>(
          builder: (_) => const MyShopPage(title:"My SHop"),
        );
      case postSalePage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<PostSalePage>(
          builder: (_) => const PostSalePage(title:"Post an ad"),
        );
      case updateSalePage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<UpdateSalePage>(
          builder: (_) => const UpdateSalePage(title:"Update an ad"),
        );
      case saleDetailsPage:
        return MaterialPageRoute<SaleDetailsPage>(
          builder: (_) => const SaleDetailsPage(title:"Ad details"),
        );

      default:
        throw RouteException("Route not found");
    }
  }

  static const loginPage = '/';
  static const homePage = '/home';
  static const helpPage = '/help';
  static const settingsPage = '/settings';

  static const marketPage = '/home/market';
  static const bookmarkPage = '/home/market/bookmark';
  static const bookmarkMapPage = '/home/market/bookmark/bookmarksmap';
  static const searchPage = '/home/market/search';
  static const resultsPage = '/home//market/search/results';
  static const resultsDetailsPage =
      '/home/market/search/results/resultsdetails';
  static const resultsDetailsMapPage =
      '/home/market/search/results/resultsdetails/resultsdetailsmap';

  static const myShopPage = '/home/myshop';
  static const postSalePage = '/home/myshop/postsale';
  static const updateSalePage = '/home/myshop/updatesale';
  static const saleDetailsPage = '/home/myshop/saledetails';
}

class RouteException implements Exception {
  final String message;
  const RouteException(this.message);
}
```

I should stress that Navigation is working in other widgets, notably the custom AppBar

Comment: Can you include your app `route`?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I ve edited the post to add the route page

Comment: After testing it, I found `onClick` isn't being called because of stack-overlay

Comment: @YeasinSheikh what do you mean by stack overlay? That a layer on top of the small FAB widget is making it unclickable ?

Comment: from my side yes, fab button works fine, but others small buttons' tap isnot working.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yes, that is exactly the problem I m having

Comment: and i think it is happening for  stack, if change the order of buttons, only last will be tappable because of stack tap priority on widget tree.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh cheers for confirming that. I ve been looking around without finding a clear answer, options now are to either try wrapping widgets in GestureDetector, or changing the Stack to a Column.

Comment: Row didnt like it, threw an Exception caught by widgets library, The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the following instead?

```
Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourScreen()));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).